# How do I install components such as Apache Drill and Apache Hue in IBM Bluemix BigInsights Apache Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, ibm-cloud, biginsights

I am new to IBM Bluemix platform and exploring its BigInsights service. I can see pre configured components such as Pig Hive Hbase and others. But I want to know How can I install services like Drill or say Hue which is not configured by default. Also ssh to cluster nodes allows restricted access with no sudo rights in case one need to run yum commands.Does bluemix allows root access as I cannot see one. Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible.

But you can use http://www.softlayer.com/ to build your own IOP (IBM Open Platform) Cluster in the cloud.

If you are interested in IBM's value-adds and you just want to try out:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4p7LDeu_qQQ it is a nice tutorial to set up your own cluster via Docker.

This tutorial should be still valid for Hue:
https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2015/06/02/deploying-hue-on-ibm-biginsights/

Installing Drill doesn't look complicated:
https://drill.apache.org/docs/installing-drill-in-distributed-mode/

In conclusion: You need to move away from Bluemix, if you want to have a more customised BigInsights. But there are options: Softlayer, AWS, .. or just on your local computer (if you got sufficient resources, since some components like Hbase need a minimum amount of nodes)